# cannot run struts2 web application on weblogic

Tags: java, struts2

I have made the struts2 web application according to the web tutorials.
It will deploy to weblogic server 10.3.6. (JDK1.6) In my developer machine, I have added the server in eclipse. But when I run it, it shows below error. I have researched in the web and tried to fix. It should be no duplicate jars found. Please help.

```
ERROR org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher - Dispatcher initialization failed
com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to load configuration.
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:418)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager$FilterInitAction.run(FilterManager.java:343)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager.loadFilter(FilterManager.java:96)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager.preloadFilters(FilterManager.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1872)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3154)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:671)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:59)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:149)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to load bean: type: class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:221)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:101)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:169)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationException: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name xwork has already been loaded by bean - zip:C:/Users/raymondchiu/.m2/repository/org/apache/struts/struts2-core/2.1.8/struts2-core-2.1.8.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:205)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
<2017年6月9日 上午11時20分31秒 CST> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101165> <Could not load user defined filter in web.xml: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.
Unable to load configuration. - bean - zip:C:/Oracle_Home/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_auto_generated_ear_/3tqe0y/war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.1.8.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterManager$FilterInitAction.run(FilterManager.java:343)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: Unable to load configuration. - bean - zip:C:/Oracle_Home/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_auto_generated_ear_/3tqe0y/war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.1.8.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:418)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: Unable to load bean: type: class:com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory - bean - zip:C:/Oracle_Home/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_auto_generated_ear_/3tqe0y/war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.1.8.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:221)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:101)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:169)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:374)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: Bean type class com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory with the name xwork has already been loaded by bean - zip:C:/Users/raymondchiu/.m2/repository/org/apache/struts/struts2-core/2.1.8/struts2-core-2.1.8.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72 - bean - zip:C:/Oracle_Home/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/_auto_generated_ear_/3tqe0y/war/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.1.8.jar!/struts-default.xml:29:72
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:205)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:101)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:169)
    at igurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:374)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktracecom.opensymphony.xwork2.config.Conf
>
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more details, e.g., where are you deploying your libraries. At a quick glance it looks like you're deploying multiple S2 libraries, e.g., both in the app and in the web server's lib directory.

Comment: Yet, Dave Newton may be correct. As when I new another project in another workspace. No this error and can publish and run.

Comment: This question has been asked multiple times in SO. This is the issue of multiple copies of struts2  jar

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue a few times, specifically when using WebLogic 10.3.x, Eclipse, and Maven.

The problem is that the WebLogic server plugin for Eclipse will add all dependencies to the classpath twice.

I have a workaround that may or may not work for you (depending on your application's architecture).

First, you must deploy the application as an **exploded archive**. You can find this setting under the WebLogic server properties in Eclipse (under the 'publishing' config node).

Second, you must deploy the application as a **war project** (as opposed to an ear).

Note that this is not an issue with newer versions of WebLogic. I deploy ear projects from within Eclipse all the time to WebLogic 12c without any issue. I only have the problem you describe when deploying to WebLogic 11g (10.3.x).